# Amavis and Spamassassin error with '.pre' files (using iRedMail)

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, amavis, iredmail

I installed iRedMail which would install amavis and spamassassin. When I test sending and receiving email, I have an error in the `/var/log/mail.log`, I see this line of error:

> postfix/amavis/smtp[14582]: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026: Connection refused

when I run this line:
`$sudo amavisd-new debug`
I see at the end of the output:

> files are in the config directory.\nAt a minimum, v320.pre loads the Check plugin which is required. Jun 12 11:58:25.764 mail.example.com /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[20040]: sd_notify (no socket): STOPPING=1\nSTATUS=TROUBLE in pre_loop_hook: Timeout::_run: check: no loaded plugin implements 'check_main': cannot scan!\nCheck that the necessary '.pre' files are in the config directory.\nAt a minimum, v320.pre loads the Check plugin which is required. Jun 12 11:58:25.764 mail.example.com /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[20040]: (!)_DIE: Suicide () TROUBLE in pre_loop_hook: Timeout::_run: check: no loaded plugin implements 'check_main': cannot scan!\nCheck that the necessary '.pre' files are in the config directory.\nAt a minimum, v320.pre loads the Check plugin which is required. Suicide () TROUBLE in pre_loop_hook: Timeout::_run: check: no loaded plugin implements 'check_main': cannot scan! Check that the necessary '.pre' files are in the config directory. At a minimum, v320.pre loads the Check plugin which is required.

This is also the output of `$spamassassin --lint -D`:

> Timeout::_run: check: no loaded plugin implements 'check_main': cannot scan! Check that the necessary '.pre' files are in the config directory. At a minimum, v320.pre loads the Check plugin which is required

I looked up in the `/etc/mail/spamassassin` directory and I can't see any '.pre' files in it.
I also searched for `v320.pre` file using this:
`$sudo find / -iname v320.pre` with no result.

If I disbale the amavis using:
`$sudo nano /etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user`
and changing these two lines:

`@bypass_virus_checks_maps = (1);`
`@bypass_spam_checks_maps  = (1);`

and then restarting the service:
`$sudo systemctl restart amavis`
and then processing the mail queue:
`$postqueue -f`
the mail server would work perfectly fine! So it is obvious that I should put some '.pre' files in the `/etc/mail/spamassassin` directory. I found out that there are some '.pre' files in this url:
https://apache.googlesource.com/spamassassin/+/trunk/rules
My question is: Is it safe to download these files and put them in my directory? Or in general where can I find '.pre' files or generate them?

Comment: Does a log from the time *spamassassin* was installed reveal why its configuration files were not copied to `/etc`?

Comment: @anx I checked the `install.log` file and there is no error regarding the apamassassin installation (or anything else). It doesn't have any information about '.pre' files. It only has these lines in it: ```[ INFO ] Configure SpamAssassin (content-based spam filter).
 + < DEBUG > Copy sample SpamAssassin config file: /path/to/iRedMail-1.4.0/samples/spamassassin/local.cf -> /etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf.
 + < DEBUG > Enable crontabs for SpamAssassin update.```

Comment: @anx I also checked the installation files: `iRedMail-1.4.0/samples/spamassassin` it only has two files in it: `local.cf` and `razor.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whom it may concern, I downloaded the whole version regarding the one that was installed on my server from (https://spamassassin.apache.org/)[https://spamassassin.apache.org/].
Then I scrolled down to `rules` directory from the downloaded files and copy `v320.pre` to my server `/etc/mail/spamassassin` directory (since v320.pre is the minimum requirement for spamassassin and amavis to work).
Then I used this command to update the rules:
`$sudo sa-update`
I restarted amavis and spamassassin services:

`$sudo systemctl restart amavis`

`$sudo systemctl restart spamassassin`

checked the debug outputs using these command lines:

`$sudo amavisd-new debug`

`$spamassassin --lint -D`

After I made sure, there is no error, I enabled the service in this file:

`$sudo nano /etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user`

and modified these lines:

> @bypass_virus_checks_maps = (0);

> @bypass_spam_checks_maps  = (0);

save and close the file, and restart the service.

`$sudo systemctl restart amavis`

To make sure everything is working find just send and receive an email. And yeah :)